# Arcpy processing pairs of shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have a problem I need to figure out but don't have idea how.
I have two separate directories with shapefiles. In dir 1. shapefile names are like 1.shp till 1000.shp. And in dir 2 W1.shp till W1000.shp. And I need arcpy script that will create pairs and process every pair. So for example 1.shp goes with W1.shp and then create intersection and save it. And every pair in the same way. Could you please help how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.path.join()` is a good way to handle these situations. It allows you to plug in the `for` loop iteration variable (i.e. in this case `fc`) into a different directory.

```
import arcpy, os

ws = r'C:\path\to\directory'
ws2 = r'C:\path\to\directory2'

outws = r'C:\path\to\directory3'

arcpy.env.workspace = ws

# List all feature classes in ws
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcs:
    # Create full paths for pair1 and pair2
    pair1 = os.path.join(ws, fc)
    pair2 = os.path.join(ws2, "W" + fc)
    outfc = os.path.join(outws, "intersected_" + fc)

    arcpy.Intersect_analysis ([pair1, pair2], outfc)
```

Or, for a pure python approach using the `glob` module:

```
import os, glob

ws = r'C:\path\to\directory'
ws2 = r'C:\path\to\directory2'

# List all feature classes in ws
fcs = glob.glob(os.path.join(ws, '*.shp'))

for fc in fcs:
    # Automatically find the pair in ws2
    pair1 = fc # Not really necessary, but for symmetry
    pair2 = os.path.join(ws2, "W" + os.path.basename(fc))

    # Do something else...
```